# Does PHP's date() method have any preconfigured date formats?

Tags: laravel

Do I really have to go look at the reference sheet every time I want to format a date?

Why not have something like 'S' map to some typical format, like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm am/pm

It seems like a common format, why not just map it to something like 'S'?

Does this exist somewhere in PHP or Laravel? If it does, I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

These constants are in the DateTimeInterface, I use ATOM alot.
Avoid using ISO8601 as it is not correct ISO8601 date.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
const string DateTimeInterface::ATOM = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::COOKIE = "l, d-M-Y H:i:s T" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::ISO8601 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::RFC822 = "D, d M y H:i:s O" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::RFC850 = "l, d-M-y H:i:s T" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::RFC1036 = "D, d M y H:i:s O" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::RFC1123 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::RFC7231 = "D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::RFC2822 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::RFC3339 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::RSS = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
const string DateTimeInterface::W3C = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Failing that you could use 'r', that will give you a date like this.
Example: Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's dates all use Carbon.

Carbon has the ability to set a "default" date format.

You can shove something like this:
`Carbon::setToStringFormat('jS \o\f F, Y g:i:s a');`

Into your bootstrap files so it's activated globally see:

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting